# How fast can I take pictures with a remote control on my Canon EOS 550D?

Tags: canon-550d, timelapse, remote

I'm using an IR LED for controlling my Canon 550D/T2i for a time lapse.

If I shoot each 6 seconds everything is fine, but I want to shoot each 1 second. Then I have problems, it shoots at random times.

I have disabled all automatic settings and I have set the lowest resolution I have.
Things are little better but not working, it shoots 10-11 photos each second but then for 5-6 seconds nothing.

Is the rate of 1 shoot per second too high?

Comment: I would reset the camera to factory default settings, and also test this out after putting your camera in manual focus. Potentially it could be searching for focus during those few seconds, and this would take that out of the equation. If you are trying to do quick shots like this, an intervalometer might work better. You could just set it to take an image each second for 30 seconds, etc.

Comment: there is manual focus!

Comment: and i want to shoot a clock following the second handle so i need each second!

Comment: For this purpose, I think you'll far better results by installing the Magic Lantern firmware and using its intervalometer function.

Comment: Suggestion non-intervalometer related: If I wanted a picture of each second on a clock, I would unplug the clock and manually advance the needle.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be but you would have trouble if long shutter noise-reduction kicks in. On some cameras it can be disabled entirely.

From your description, it sounds like it *could* be a slow card. You lowered the resolution which should help but I have no idea how slow your card is. Try a faster card.

Comment: faster card?? are there sd card with different velocity?? i didn't know it.

Comment: SD/SDHC/SDXC cards come in different classes, although some manufactuers label them with X-speed (1X = 150 KB/s) or simply MB/s. The higher the class, the better. Faster cards allow to empty the card buffer faster and avoid the camera stopping for a while as it empties like like you described. The same will happen when you shoot using the continuous drive. Keep in mind that you do not necessarily needs the faster card, only one which is fast enough. Still, the last 95MB/s card I bought cost less than $50 USD, so no need to skimp either.